# Etiqeuta Iframe vs video

Tags: html, html5, video, iframe

Perdon por la pregunta tan tonta, pero pero si quiero copiar un video de youtube, con el codigo de insercion utiliza la etiqueta , y  todo funciona.

```
<iframe width="604" height="1073" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uMpQkcuX1Wk"
            title="Michael Jordan’s historic free throw line dunk!" frameborder="0"
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
            allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Pero si quiero utilizar la etiqueta video, y copiar en el src="youtube.com" , el enlace no funciona.

Alguien sabe el porque ?, y cuando conviende utilizar iframe y cuando la etiqueta video?

Comment: video solo es para fuentes de video tipo mp4 o formatos soportados del navegador
    el IFRAME es un marco que carga una pagina de otro sitio, osea tu iframe solo habre una ventana del navegador hacia el sitio de youtube donde ellos cargan el video y tu no lo puedes controlar. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe